# Prevent multiple definitions of element in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to write an XSLT stylesheet which copies one XML document into another using a number of generic templates to perform operations such as inserting an attribute on matched nodes. The problem I am having is that a requirement of these templates is to make a copy of the element node which means calling it more than once will produce two copies of the node.

The Attribute insertion template is written like this:

```
<xsl:template match = "DO_NOT_MATCH" name = "InsertAttribute">
    <xsl:param name = "attributeName"/>
    <xsl:param name = "attributeValue"/>
    <xsl:element name = "{name(.)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select = "@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name = "{$attributeName}">
            <xsl:value-of select = "$attributeValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I am calling this template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
    <xsl:call-template name = "InsertAttribute">
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeName" select = '"NewAttribute1"'/>
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeValue" select = '4'/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name = "InsertAttribute">
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeName" select = '"NewAttribute2"'/>
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeValue" select = '6'/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

This will transform an XML document like the following:

```
<root>
    <Object/>
</root>
```

...into this:

```
<root>    
    <Object NewAttribute1="4"/>
    <Object NewAttribute2="6"/>
</root>
```

I'm looking for a way to get the below output without having to use two different stylesheets in succession or manually combining the two template calls into a single operation. Do any of you know a way to do this?

```
<root>    
    <Object NewAttribute1="4" NewAttribute2="6"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the object creation and the attribute processing into the other template and then only create the new attributes in the named template:

```
<xsl:template match = "DO_NOT_MATCH" name = "InsertAttribute">
    <xsl:param name = "attributeName"/>
    <xsl:param name = "attributeValue"/>
    <xsl:attribute name = "{$attributeName}">
        <xsl:value-of select = "$attributeValue"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Object">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:call-template name = "InsertAttribute">
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeName" select = '"NewAttribute1"'/>
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeValue" select = '4'/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name = "InsertAttribute">
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeName" select = '"NewAttribute2"'/>
        <xsl:with-param name = "attributeValue" select = '6'/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a good idea but I'm having a problem using it. I get a warning that I "Cannot write an attribute node when no element start tag is open". Presumably this is because the function is separated by the function call which is why I had the element definition in the "InsertAttribute" template in the first place. Is this an XSLT 2.0+ thing, I'm still using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamKT works fine as far as I can tell, you will need to show the code causing the error.

Comment: It seems to be working now, I'm not sure what was wrong with the version I tested before. I think this approach should get me closer to the end result. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are over-engineering this. XSLT already includes an instruction for adding an attribute to the current element. I don't see what advantage is gained by having a named template for the same purpose.

In the given example, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="NewAttribute1">4</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="NewAttribute2">6</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or even simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
     <Object NewAttribute1="4" NewAttribute2="6"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you have a scenario that wouldn't be covered by this method, then post an example of that.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because I have a lot of conversions operations to make (~2000) which are currently described in a non-xslt syntax. I can use REGEX to convert them to XSLT as long as I can create a generic format for each of the operations. What I'm trying to avoid is creating a customized template for each of these conversion operations as it would take too much time.

Comment: If you have 2 "conversions operations", one saying "*add attribute Y to element X*" and the other saying "*add attribute Z to element X*" there is no way you can translate them both to two independent and similar XSLT instructions, without adding a third one.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case but I'm still relatively new to XSLT so I wanted to check. Thanks for your help Michael.

Comment: BTW, you **do** have a third one: it's your template matching `Object` that calls the other two.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you meant. The problem is that I don't want them to be independent. Each one currently copies the matched parent element in order to add a new attribute. Since they are independent they will output two new elements. The suggestion in the other post looks promising as it only creates one new node but I may be having problems with my parser I need to look into first.

Comment: "*Since they are independent they will output two new elements.*" The idea is that the third one will do that, and the two will only add attributes to it. This is basically what Martin Honnen suggested too. My suggestion is to translate the two into `xsl:attribute` instructions instead of named templates.